# Why we can't feel the different parts of ear during hearing which is mentioned in all biology books?

Tags: human-anatomy

We can't feel our outer ear, middle ear and inner ear during hearing something. Why is that such a complex phenomenon is happening all the time but still we don't have any clue regarding that in our practical life?  We just get the sensation of hearing something and get no sensation/feeling how  different parts of our ear work all together .why all these happening within our ear and we never conscious about them ? In fact , we can know them only after studying biology.

Comment: Can you think of a benefit we would gain? I can see only drawbacks, like "investment" in additional sensors and extra processing.

Answer (score -1):

Going to be productive instead of posting unhelpful snarky comments and downvoting.

You can only perceive what you have nerves for. Considering humans are unaware of all the rattling going on between the eardrum and inner ear, the only logical explanation is that there are no nerves in the region made to perceive said rattling.

Comment: That's not quite true actually, the brain is really good at filtering out / ignoring unnecessary (mostly constant) sensory input. For example there are blood vessels above the retina, which you normally can't see (I think with a quickly moving light source or something like that you can make the shadows visible)

Comment: Your comment isn't quite true actually, tell that to the many people living with chronic pain. I'm sure their brain is doing an excellent job at filtering out or ignoring it. /sarcasm

Comment: I didn't want to say that the brain filters out all constant (sensory) input (pain is different than normal sensory input anyway), just that it can do it - therefore the 'logical conclusion' that any area we don't actively notice doesn't have nerves is wrong.